# pip failed installing jq dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I managed to install other needed packages, like arrow but i am not able to install `jq`. https://pypi.org/project/jq/

I tried to install `jq` on Win10 (with proxy restrictions, python 3.7.7) with this command:

```
(project) C:\project>pip --proxy=https://xxx:8080 install jq
```

Output:

```
Collecting jq
  Using cached jq-1.0.1.tar.gz (59 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\venv\project\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\venv\project\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Us
ers\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zaiv6qw7\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=43' wheel requ
ests certifi
cwd: None
  Complete output (7 lines):
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConn
ection object at 0x000002B85F072E48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConn
ection object at 0x000002B85F07DBC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConn
ection object at 0x000002B85F07C5C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConn
ection object at 0x000002B85F07C3C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConn
ection object at 0x000002B85F081648>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=43 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=43
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\venv\project\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-
installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zaiv6qw7\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/si
mple -- 'setuptools>=43' wheel requests certifi Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also upgraded pip and setuptools to version 47.3.0
Can anybody give me a hint, what could be the solution for my issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: could you please reformat your question? [how do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Is your proxy intercepting https? (Some "security" solutions perform a MITM on https connections). Windows might be accepting those connections because your organisation may install a "CA" certificate for its "security" solution. Those additional certificates are not used by many other software solutions as default (git, java, pip, ...)

You could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-pip-in-windows maybe that solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you need an https proxy instead? You can get more information about the root cause by running the command in verbose mode.

```
pip -v --proxy=https://xxx:8080 install jq
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue trying to install django_microsoft_auth. My `--proxy` setting allows me to collect that package, but for some reason when it tries the "Installing build dependencies" step, it errors out because it can't collect `setuptools` from pypi.org. Why can't it just use my local copy of `setuptools`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your setuptools and pip version.

`python -m pip --proxy=https://xxx:8080 install --upgrade pip setuptools jq`

look at [urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed>？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835767/urllib-error-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11002-getaddrinfo-failed#35835866)

Comment: i tried your suggested command, but i get the same issue.