Unable to properly generate dalle-3 logo images using python
If I am giving prompt in azure open ai studio > playground > dall-e-3 using api version 2024-05-01-preview" .it is generating perfect image but the same prompt if I am using it in my python to generate a total different kind of logo is generated (it is not in readable lang The image was generated but not as logo) in python i am using api version 2023-06-01-preview but if i am using 2024-05-01-preview" it is showing
error :resource not found how to  set that
prompt is: create a circular logo on the name: python - python beginner and also Raj name on the circle border
i have changed openai==0.28 to latest openai version but still unable to get it
openai =  1.42.0
then i got the error
Error generating image:
You tried to access openai.Image, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.
You can run openai migrate to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.
Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. pip install openai==0.28
A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742
jayashankarGS code error :

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_transports\default.py",
line 69, in map_httpcore_exceptions
yield   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_transports\default.py",
line 233, in handle_request
resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpcore_sync\connection_pool.py",
line 216, in handle_request
raise exc from None   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpcore_sync\connection_pool.py",
line 196, in handle_request
response = connection.handle_request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpcore_sync\connection.py",
line 99, in handle_request
raise exc   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpcore_sync\connection.py",
line 76, in handle_request
stream = self._connect(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpcore_sync\connection.py",
line 122, in _connect
stream = self._network_backend.connect_tcp(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpcore_backends\sync.py",
line 205, in connect_tcp
with map_exceptions(exc_map):   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\contextlib.py",
line 158, in exit
self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpcore_exceptions.py",
line 14, in map_exceptions
raise to_exc(exc) from exc httpcore.ConnectError: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai_base_client.py",
line 973, in _request
response = self._client.send(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_client.py",
line 914, in send
response = self._send_handling_auth(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_client.py",
line 942, in _send_handling_auth
response = self._send_handling_redirects(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_client.py",
line 979, in _send_handling_redirects
response = self._send_single_request(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_client.py",
line 1015, in _send_single_request
response = transport.handle_request(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_transports\default.py",
line 232, in handle_request
with map_httpcore_exceptions():   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\contextlib.py",
line 158, in exit
self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_transports\default.py",
line 86, in map_httpcore_exceptions
raise mapped_exc(message) from exc httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"c:\Users\Comp\Desktop\testing.py", line 12, in 
result = client.images.generate(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai\resources\images.py",
line 253, in generate
return self._post(
^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai_base_client.py",
line 1260, in post
return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File
"C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai_base_client.py",
line 937, in request
return self._request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai_base_client.py",
line 997, in _request
return self._retry_request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai_base_client.py",
line 1075, in _retry_request
return self._request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai_base_client.py",
line 997, in _request
return self._retry_request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai_base_client.py",
line 1075, in _retry_request
return self._request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai_base_client.py",
line 1007, in _request
raise APIConnectionError(request=request) from err
openai.APIConnectionError: Connection error. PS C:\Users\Comp>

Prudhvi code:
import openai
import os

# Set your Azure OpenAI credentials and endpoint
openai.api_key = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxx")
openai.api_base = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
openai.api_type = "azure"             
openai.api_version = "2023-06-01-preview"  # Adjust this based on your Azure API version

def generate_image(prompt):
    try:
        # Make a request to Azure OpenAI to generate an image with DALL-E 3
        response = openai.Image.create(
            prompt=prompt,
            n=1,  # Number of images
            size="1024x1024"  # Adjust size if needed
        )

        # Extract the URL of the generated image
        image_url = response['data'][0]['url']
        print(f"Image URL: {image_url}")

        return image_url

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating image: {e}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example prompt to generate an image
    prompt = "  create a circular logo on the name: python - python beginner   "
    image_url = generate_image(prompt)

    if image_url:
        print(f"Generated image available at: {image_url}")


You tried to access openai.Image, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0.
Also, according to this documentation you use Azureopenai class providing the model name.
Make sure you have already deployed the dall-e-3 model.
If you deploying the model freshly you need to wait 4-7 minutes.

Use below code.
import os
import httpx
from openai import AzureOpenAI
from PIL import Image

client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_version="2024-05-01-preview",  
    api_key="131xxxxxxxxxx",  
    azure_endpoint="https://opexx.openai.azure.com/"
)
            
result = client.images.generate(
    model="dall-e-3",
    prompt="create a circular logo on the name: python - python beginner and also Raj name on the circle border",
    n=1
 )
            
image_dir = os.path.join(os.curdir, 'images')
            

if not os.path.isdir(image_dir):
    os.mkdir(image_dir)
            
image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, 'generated_image.png')
            
image_url = result.data[0].url  
generated_image = httpx.get(image_url).content  
with open(image_path, "wb") as image_file:
    image_file.write(generated_image)
    
image  =  Image.open(image_path)
image

Output:

This code can be used for both dall-e-2 and dall-e-3.

uninstalled openai and re-install openai= 1.42.0
got the below error:
File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_transports\default.py", line 69, in map_httpcore_exceptions
yield
File "C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\httpx_transports\default.py", line 233, in handle_request
resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Are you running the given code above? Please add full error details.

For my code i had runned with that openai version got the error which i mentioned above my code  in main question

I have runned your code the error is top big unable to paste it here

As I mentioned openai version greater than 1 is not supported for using openai.Image. refer my code

Ok. Give the exact error not the whole.

I tried your code i will put the error in the main question
as jayashankarGs code error kindly check

I have added in the question with jayashankarGS code error kindly check

Have you deployed the model in your openai workspace?

yes i deployed dall-e-3 in azure open ai studio and tested in playground also

Have you configured any vnet or firewall?

No I didn't configured any

Try this generated_image = requests.get(image_url).content  instead of httpx in my code.

Also refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835767/urllib-error-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11002-getaddrinfo-failed.

changed got a lengthy  error in short the error was The error:
you're encountering is a connection issue, specifically an openai.APIConnectionError. This error occurs when your script is unable to connect to the OpenAI API, and it seems to stem from a DNS resolution problem ([Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed).

Check the steps mentioned here. https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6897191-apiconnectionerror

But for your code if i change old api version images are generated from prompts so i believe there must no connection issues .

2024-05-01-preview api version raising the issue?

yes "2023-06-01-preview only this api version is working but images are not properly generated according to the prompts

your code  worked. Thank you
